# como realizar una consultar mysql para insertar datos mysql y que no me inserte datos que se encuentran repetidos en la tabla?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Esta es la consulto que ejecuto actualmente, pero quisiera que me identifique si hay nombre y apellidos repetidos en la tablaejemplo1 antes que me inserte los datos.

```
insert into basedatos1.tablaejemplo1(id,nombre,apellido)
select null, a.nombre,a.apellido
from basedatos2.tablaejemplo2 a
Group By a.nombre, a.apellido
order by a.nombre ASC
```

Comment: Digamos que hay nombres que pueden repertirse pero tienen apellidos distintos en ese caso deberia colocar ambos columnas UNIQUE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es evitar insertar **"nombre + apellido"** que ya existe en la otra tabla, pero que si puedas insertar si hay apellidos repetidos o nombres repetidos por separado.

prueba este código:

```
insert into basedatos1.tablaejemplo1(id,nombre,apellido)
select  null,nombre, apellido
from basedatos2.tablaejemplo2 b
WHERE  CONCAT_WS(' ', b.nombre, b.apellido) NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', a.nombre, a.apellido) FROM basedatos1.tablaejemplo1 a) 
Group By b.nombre, b.apellido
order by b.nombre ASC
```

La idea  de esta consulta es  concatenar el nombre y el apellido, así de esta manera es mas fácil comparar con la otra tabla, así solo  se rechazaran los que sean idénticos tanto en nombre  como en apellido, pero no a los que contengan apellidos iguales y nombres diferentes y viceversa.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me funciono